# Reason to why email will not show in library?

Tags: document-library, email

I have setup a list to have incoming mail enabled but when I send an email nothing pops up in the list itself. I can see it enter the drop fodler and then disappear but it will not show in the library.

Anyone had this issue before? I had it working on a different library a while back which has now been removed and need this one to work. Any help would be fantastic.

Regards.

EDIT: When I select "Save original e-mail" it will show in the library, when removed it will not show.

Answer (score 1):

Which is it? A library or a list? Your title and tag contradict each other.

Are the incoming email settings allowing anyone to send to the list or is strictly based on the permissions of the list?

If you are trying to save the email itself, you'd most likely want to use a document library and not a list, unless you're talking about a calendar. If you are trying to save it in a library and there are no attachments and you set the save original email to no, then there isn't anything to save.

Comment: It's currently set to accept from all senders and I am also using a document library (sorry for the confusion)